# Writing items from list into different files Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I can write items from list to a single file like:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in all_news:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

But how I can write each item to a separate file?

Comment: Invert the `for` and `with`, and have some list of names to write to, and sure. But you'd need a lot more info on how you expect to choose which files to write to.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give us the requirements for the individual filenames, but here is an example that uses a sequential number for each given filename.

```
count = 0
for item in all_news:
    count += 1
    filename = '{}.txt'.format(count)
    with open(filename, 'w') as f_out:
        f.write('{}\n'.format(item))
```

Comment: `for count,item in enumerate(all_news,1):` and you can skip the `count=0` and `count+=1`

Comment: You.  I like you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
all_news = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for item in all_news:
    # every file will get the item name
    # if there aren't repeated items
    with open(f'{item}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

If in the list are more items with the same name:

```
for count, item in enumerate(all_news, 1):
    # every file will get the the index as name
    with open(f'{count}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'only 2 files - ups' ?

Ah. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You have to open a new file on each element of the list, and you will need a counter to ensure have separated filenames (or a second list).

```
counter=0
for item in all_news:
    with open('your_file_'+str(counter)+'.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
        counter = counter + 1
```

This will write each element in files like `you_file_0.txt`, `your_file_1.txt`, etc

*(I'm just elaborating what ShadowRanger already commented above).*

Comment: You can't concatenate integers and strings like that.  You could use `str(counter)`, however.  Consider using `str.format()`.